# Почему не получается динамически подгрузить сайт, так скажем в "песочницу"

Tags: jquery, javascript, http, html

```
<div id="sandbox"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yandex.ru/',
    success: function(response) { $('#sandbox').html(response); }
});
</script>
```

Даёт пустоту, хотя `http://localhost/test/` грузит отлично (там простенькая html страничка). Если кого смущает наличие тегов `<html><head>` в блоке #sandbox, так же пробовал `$('#sandbox').append(response);` то же самое, с локалхоста грузит, с интернета - нет. Может как нибудь нарушается политика безопасности?

### Лимит комментарий закончился видимо,

Для [[@NoName](/users/12132/noname)](/users/12132/noname), да вы правы, для конкретного блока <base href="" /> не прописать, но можно попробовать изловчиться как нибудь так:

```
$('#sandbox *').attr('src', 'http://anylink.com/' + $(this).attr('src'));
$('#sandbox a').attr('href', 'http://anylink.com/' + $(this).attr('href'));
```

Comment: да - нарушается политика безопасности, вы не можете грузить сайт который не разрешил для вашего сайта Cross Domain запросы. гуглим CORS.

Comment: Спасибо я нашёл другой вариант! Сделали бы вы ответом, я бы принял, не люблю вопросы без ответа.

Comment: Странная вещь получается, таким образом:

    <div id="sandbox">
     <?php $kx = file_get_contents('http://yandex.ru/'); echo $kx; ?>
    </div> 

ничего не нарушается?

Comment: а если в том контенте есть изображения, пути которых относительные, думаете, они будут грузиться?

Comment: При указании `<base href="http://yandex.ru/"></base>` думаю да. Проверил так и есть. Если честно для меня это стало не хилым таким открытием: скажем так получить iframe к которому есть доступ. Указав размеры блока и `overflow: auto;`

Comment: указывая в php вы не заставляете браузер клиента обращаться к яндексу, вы как-бы проксируете данные, соответственно куки пользовательские яндексовые не будут использованы при соединении, это и есть причина установки правила безопасности.

Comment: @Олег Б, хочу докопаться!)... до истины. Если на странице уже есть свой base href, второй можно прописывать?

Comment: [Узнала][1]. "Если ошибочно добавлено несколько <base> с разными href, то применяется только первый, остальные игнорируются". Значит в таком случае картинки не загрузятся.


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/metadannye-dokumenta/element-base

Comment: Зря вы мне не верите:

    <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="http://hashcode.ru"></base>
    </head><body>
    
    <div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #aaa;" id="sandbox">
       <?php $kx = file_get_contents('http://hashcode.ru/'); echo $kx; ?>
    </div></body></html>

Запустите и увидите что всё отображается прекрасно, теперь уберите 3 строчку (<base href.. ) и убедитесь что всё поплыло ;)


Comment: допустим, у меня на движке уже есть для каждого сайта свой base href в начале страницы. Если я захочу подгрузить контент с другого сайта на свою страницу, предварительно прописав второй base href, то он, соответственно, проигнорируется, я вот что хотела сказать)

--------
upd: да знаю я ответ, парсить, дописывать абсолютные пути и все такое..